# Calling an ActionResult in a controller that isn't Home

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a bit of javascript that is trying to POST to an ActionResult in a controller called Tables.  For some reason the routing isn't working.

My Javascript (in script tags at the top of my view):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#somevalue').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("Tables/GetExpenseTypes")'
    });
})
```

My Controller:

```
public class TablesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetExpenseTypes(string term)
    {
        return Json(Blah); 
    }
}
```

Whenever I execute the call, it returns a 404 Not Found error.  When I look at the request, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:56569/Home/Tables/GetExpenseTypes
```

If it matters, this is my RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
    UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Why does my request want to go to the Home controller no matter what?  If I precede the controller/Action with a forward slash:

```
$('#somevalue').autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("/Tables/GetExpenseTypes")'
});
```

It makes no difference, the request is still routed to the Home controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the `Url.Action` helper incorrectly

Your current code is calling [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String%29)

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName
)
```

and you are passing `Tables/GetExpenseTypes` as the value of the `actionName` parameter. The helper method will use the current controller as the controller when building the url to this action method, hence you are getting `/Home/Tables/GetExpenseTypes`

You should use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29)

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

where you pass the action name and controller name as separate parameters

```
source: '@Url.Action("GetExpenseTypes","Tables")'
```

This will generate the correct url.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks @Shyju